# How youtube works in web

Tags: web, youtube

I how youtube works. I am very confused that without using `src` attributes in `HTMLVideoElement` and how youtube show **ads** in videoes and controls the **quality** of videoes.

Comment: Welcome to SO! YouTube is pretty complex, I'd imagine. It's out of scope to ask how it works in one question. We're looking for practical, answerable, specific programming problems, so even if you narrow it down, it's still probably off-topic as defined in the [help].

Answer (score 0):

For Youtube Videos, you typically wants to use `<iframe` or `<em>` tags. `<video>` works best with .mp4, .avi files. How Youtube show ads and choose video quality in your page is uncontrollable by yourself.